# Saving and fingerprint template or simply fingerpirint data in Django project

Tags: django, database, postgresql, fingerprint

I am trying to find a way to save fingerprint data in a database within a Django project, my idea after doing some research is that I want to allow users to upload their fingerprint template to the website, but I didn't find yet the best way to store the fingerprint data if there's a better to allow users providing their fingerprint data to the backend and how the data is going to be stored in the database, I appreciate  it and thanks in advance
note: the database manager that I am using is postgresql

Comment: I convert template into byte array then Base64 string then saved it into DB. then retrieve it and then decode the base64

Comment: @the3plus, did you find any solution to your problem? I need to do this as well